# Image Binding not showing iOS Maui

Tags: c#, .net, maui

Im having this issue on where Images that are using binding aren't showing up on iOS. All my images are inside a resource folder and then inside a images folder. If I don't use binding on the images they show up just fine On Android the images are showing up just fine

Here is my xaml:

```
 <StackLayout Spacing="0">
        <Label x:Name="DisconnectedLabel" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource Secondary}, Light={StaticResource Accent}}" 
                   Text="Disconnected From Server" IsVisible="false" BackgroundColor="DarkRed"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="16">
        </Label>
        <RefreshView x:DataType="local:MowersViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <CollectionView BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource Accent}, Light={StaticResource Secondary}}" x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid RowDefinitions="90" ColumnDefinitions="90,90,*" x:DataType="model:Mower" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource Accent}, Light={StaticResource Secondary}}">
                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:DataType="model:Mower" Source="{Binding MowersPageImage}" Aspect="AspectFill" Margin="5"/>
                            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0,10,0,0">
                                <Label   Text="{Binding MachineSerialNumber}" 
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource Secondary}, Light={StaticResource Accent}}"
                                FontSize="16" />
                                <Label  Text="{Binding CompanyName}" 
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource Secondary}, Light={StaticResource Accent}}" 
                                FontSize="13" />
                            </VerticalStackLayout>
                            <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5"  x:DataType="model:Mower" HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource Accent}, Light={StaticResource Secondary}}">
                                <Button x:Name="ButtonConfigure" Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Configure" HeightRequest="45" IsVisible="{Binding CanConfigure}"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MowersViewModel}}, Path=ConfigurePushed}"       
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                <Button x:Name="ButtonConnect"  Text="{Binding ConnectButtonString}" IsVisible="{Binding Online}"  HeightRequest="45"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MowersViewModel}}, Path=ConnectPushed}"     
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MowersViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"        
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </RefreshView>
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is the lines where the images are supposed to be bound too:

```
async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Items.Clear(); 

            // add mowers that we are connected to
            var sorted = new List<MowerData>((IEnumerable<MowerData>)online_mowers_);
            sorted.Sort((x, y) => (int)x.serial_number - (int)y.serial_number);
            foreach (var m in sorted)
            {
                var new_item = new Mower();
                new_item.MachineSerialNumber = m.serial_number.ToString();
                new_item.CompanyName = "";// todo fill me in?
                new_item.Connected = m.connected;
                new_item.OtherUserConnected = m.other_user_connected;
                new_item.Online = true;
                new_item.AccentColor = m.GetAccentColor();
                if (new_item.AccentColor == Color.FromRgb(1, 0, 1))
                {
                    new_item.MowersPageImage = "Resources/Images/mower_active_purple.png";
                }
                else if (new_item.AccentColor == Color.FromRgb(1, 1, 1))
                {
                    new_item.MowersPageImage = "Resources/Images/mower_active_grey.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    new_item.MowersPageImage = "Resources/Images/mower_active_blue.png";
                }
                new_item.CanConfigure = App.IsTechnician || m.connected;
                Items.Add(new_item);
            }

            var items = (await DataStore.GetItemsAsync(true)).ToList();
            items.Sort((x, y) => (int)int.Parse(x.MachineSerialNumber) - (int)int.Parse(y.MachineSerialNumber));
            foreach (var i in items)
            {
                bool found = false;
                i.MowersPageImage = "Resources/Images/mower_offline.png"; //off
                for (int j = 0; j < Items.Count; j++)
                {
                    var item = Items[j];
                    if (item.MachineSerialNumber == i.MachineSerialNumber)
                    {
                        found = true;
                        item.CompanyName = i.CompanyName;
                        Items.RemoveAt(j);
                        Items.Insert(j, item);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!found)
                {
                    i.CanConfigure = false;
                    Items.Add(i);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

I tried changing all the paths for the image didn't do anything. Then tried a static Image that one worked

Comment: you should not need the path, just the image name.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#download-images

Answer (score 1):

A method is to set your images's `Build Action` to `Embedded resource` and add a new property `MySource` in your item.

Just as follows:

```
 public ImageSource MySource { get; set; }
```

then set value for `MySource` as follows:

```
 MySource = ImageSource.FromResource("RefreshViewDemo.Resources.Images.sleep.png",typeof(MowersViewModel).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
```

And bind like this:

```
<Image   Source="{Binding MySource}" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="50"   HeightRequest="50" />
```

**Note:**

1. `RefreshViewDemo` is the name of my app,you can change it to yours.
2. Please change your images' `Build Action` to `Embedded resource`